# pip install -e svn+ssh do not take the user

Tags: svn, pip

If I do :

```
svn co svn+ssh://svn@10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config cidb_config_pipenv
```

It works, But if I do :

```
pip install -e svn+ssh://svn@10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config#egg=cidb_config_pipenv

Obtaining cidb_config_pipenv from svn+ssh://svn@10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config#egg=cidb_config_pipenv
```

It strips the 'svn@' :

```
Checking out svn+ssh://10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config to /root/.virtualenvs/root-PB1MQnVC/src/cidb-config-pipenv
```

So it tries to log in the svn server with another user than 'svn' and it fails.

In pip documentation, I see it is possible to use svn+ssh but there is no example : Have I the right syntax to specify the user to use to log into the svn server ?

EDIT : The only solution I found is to force username in SSH tunnel definition in ~/.subversion/config :

```
[tunnels]
ssh = ssh -l svn
```

This is really ugly but it works.

Comment: `pip` splits username/password out of SVN URL and [passes](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/737dfbfc71490b41ab92c6d49b0c303c0e197f46/src/pip/_internal/vcs/subversion.py#L263) them in `--username/--password` command line parameters.

Comment: The problem is that at the end, pip is not using the username specified in the url. In addition, --username option is not recognized

Comment: Your `svn` doesn't recognize `--username`? That should be reported to `pip` bug tracker.

Comment: Finally, it is not a pip bug, but a SVN one : when putting in verbose mode pip is calling svn checkout with a --username. But that is SVN which does not the job. svn co --username does not work (on ubuntu and centos at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn+ssh` uses different [(ssh) authentication](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ssh-auth-cache) so normal `--username` auth doesn't work. To avoid `pip` passing `--username` to `svn` you have to avoid `svn@` in URL. And to pass the proper ssh key you have to redefine ssh command. Something like that (provide the path to the real key):

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.svn"
```

In your case it could be

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -l svn"
export SVN_SSH
```

Verify it works:

```
svn co svn+ssh://10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config cidb_config_pipenv
```

Run pip:

```
pip install -e svn+ssh://10.210.1.24/cidb/V1/trunk/config#egg=cidb_config_pipenv
```

Comment: why pip is using --username when detecting a '@' in the URL if it is not taken in account by svn+ssh ???

Comment: I think `pip` doesn't look at `+ssh` part of the URL and just passes the username if it exists in the URL. This is probably a bug and should be reported to `pip` bug tracker.

Answer (score 3):

When putting in verbose mode one can see that pip is calling svn checkout with a --username. But that is SVN which does not the job.

```
svn checkout --username myuser svn+ssh://host/path
```

does not work (on ubuntu and centos at least) : the username is not taken in account. SVN only accept that :

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://myuser@host/path
```

The hack I found : use '%40' instead of '@' so pip will not detect a username in the url and do not call svn with --username option.
So now I can do :

```
pip -e svn+ssh://myuser%40host/path#egg=myproject
```

It is ugly, may be I have to open a issue for pip and/or svn ...